# How to export PDF file in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two views. One is to show filter view (View 1). Another one is to get data from filter view and then export to PDF file (View 2). It means that when "Print" is clicked, PDF file will be exported and View 2 will be view of PDF file with data of View 1.

Now I dont know how to get data from View 1 and show into View 2.

Here is my code:

View1:

```
<form method="get">
    <select name="type" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">All types</option>
        @foreach ($types as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}" @if ($request->type == $item->id) selected @endif>{{ $item->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<a href="pdf">Print</a>
<br><br>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($data as $q)
            <?php $typeName = App\Type::find($q->type_id);?>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $q->id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $q->content }}</td>
                <td>{{ $typeName->name }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

View2:
This view will be shown at PDF file but I dont know how to get value from View1

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Type</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

FilterController:

```
public function getFilter(Request $request){
        $types = Type::all();
        $model = Question::where('id', '>', 0)->with('types');

        if (isset($request->type))
            $model = $model->where('type_id', $request->type);
        $data = $model->paginate(15)->appends(request()->query());

        return view('View1', compact( 'data', 'request', 'types'));
    }
```

PrintController:

```
public function getValueFromView2(){
//I've to write something to get value from View1
}
public function getPDF(){
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('View2');
        return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
}
```

View1 with filter function is working fine. What I want is to export PDF file with data of View1 after filtering

Comment: you need to create a route to call view2

Comment: Route::get('filter','FilterController@getFilter');
Route::get('pdf','PrintController@getPDF');

Comment: my two-routes ..

Comment: okay now `dd` in your getPDF controller

Comment: please tell when you click `Print` does your controller called

Comment: yes. i called and exported PDF file successfully with HTML, no data cause I have not written function to get data from View1 yet

Comment: I want that after fitering in View1, the result will be exported to PDF with new view (View2)

Answer (score 0):

This is really very straight if you can change how you are trying to do atm.

Change your method getPDF to accept a get param names `type`.

```
public function getPDF(){
    $type = $this->input('type');

    // get your data here in this call using the parameter(s)
    $model = $model->where('type_id', $type);
    $data = $model->get();

    $view2 = \View::make('view2', ['data', $data]);
    $view2Str = $view1->render();

    // Check the PDF documentation how to pass html and print pdf.
   // I'm assuming this is how the library loads view, as I haven't used this myself.
    $pdf = PDF::loadView( $view2Str );
    return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
}
```

On the print link pass the parameter `type` to as query string and make the link to  the getPDF method;

Comment: Your solution is to export PDF with all HTML from View1, right? I just want to export with new view (only table)

Comment: No, Use view2 in this function, I've updated the code as well. the view2 will have table only and it will print table only in the pdf. (P.S. I mistakenly wrote view1 instead of  view2 before, corrected)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted by clicking `tick` if it solved your problem.

Comment: I got this: undefined variable $model, $view1 and $view2 unused.

Comment: @Ben you have to use your models, i just gave you an example following your code in question.